# Running Turtlebot_gazebo error

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run turtlebot_gazebo but I have some problems.
Here's the subject in details. I'm running ROS kinetic which is supposed that it can't link to gazebo as far as I know. I installed gazebo with the help of your site, however, the package I got and installed was called turtlebot_simulator, and turtlebot_gazebo was inside it (if I misunderstood the thing let me know). I tried to launch it using " $ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch" but this didn't work. Finally, I browsed to folder "launch" inside turtlebot_gazebo and tried to launch it using "$ roslaunch turtlebot_world.launch" and it gives me the following error:

Invalid  tag: environment variable 'TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE' is not set.

Arg xml is 
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

how can I fix it?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245396/running-turtlebot_gazebo-error/) by [Mina](https://answers.ros.org/users/28187/mina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-09-15**:
[Duplicate](https://answers.ros.org/question/208287/how-to-configure-environment-parameter-turtlebot_gazebo_world_file/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try setting the variable TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE:

`export TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world"`

---

Originally posted by [Vash](https://answers.ros.org/users/29549/vash/) with karma: 16 on 2017-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0